# Scrapy - scrape xml sitemap then follow links

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I started to learn scrapy and I would like to scrape one sitemap.xml to scrape all the pages inside it and then scrape a specific link inside the page from the sitemap.

For example:

On my sitemap, I have link1. I go to link1 and inside the page, I would like to scrape a specific link called linkA to get the content page of this link.

First, I define the regex rule for *parse_step1*. It allows me to get specific urls from the sitemap. It works well.

Then, I don't know how to do for telling my scraper *"scrape the page from the link, find a specific url and scrape the page content of this specific url"*.

I tried to add a second rule that is validated by regex, but I'm not able to make it work.

```
class SiteSpider(SitemapSpider):
    name = 'site'
    allowed_domains = ['domain.fr']
    # generate_start_urls()
    sitemap_urls = ["https://domain.fr/mainsitemap.xml"]
    sitemap_rules = [('^.*\/([a-zA-Z]{2})\/\/?.*', 'parse_step1'),
                     ('.*\/[0-9]{2}', 'parse_step2')
                     ]
```

Any insights?

Comment: do you have a url that I can test this on?

Answer (score 0):

1. You have a link to a website to pass into your Scrapy script
2. You get some other link during scrapping
3. Pass this link to your Scrapy script
4. Repeat

E.g. if there's Site1 with link1 and link2 and following link1 you get to a Site2 with link3 ... So here you could use `Depth First Search algorithm` to implement it.

-> you can store all your collected links in some list. And add a counter at the beginning of the parser function. So every time you go to another link - add 1 to your counter - that would be the index of current link. Once website doesn't have any link - you will go to the latest unparsed link (e.g. when you got two of them and followed the first one). You can implement it via `recursion` call of your function.

---

I can also see another approach using `xml.etree.ElementTree` (since you work with xml document):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et 
import pandas as pd

def parse_xml(path) -> pd.DataFrame:
    tree = et.parse(path)
    root = tree.getroot()

    for child in root:
        attr1 = child[0].attrib['attr1']
        attr2 = child[0].attrib['attr2']
        attr3 = child[1].attrib['attr3']
```